# Insert and Delete multi queries in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I have the following queries for inserting and deleting records from preorder traversal database. I am using codeigniter and dont know how to fire multiple queries in it. I tried following queries but not firing properly in codeigniter and firing properly using phpmyadmin.

**Query for Inserting record into the database:**

```
$level = $_GET['level'] + 1;
$rgt = $_GET['rgt'] + 1;
if ($_GET['level'] == 0) {
    $sql = "UPDATE xp_subunit SET lft = lft+2, rgt=rgt+2 WHERE rgt > " . $_GET['rgt'] . "; ";
    $sql .="INSERT INTO xp_subunit SET level=" . $level . ", lft =" . $_GET['rgt'] . ", rgt =  " . $rgt . " , name = '" . $_GET['name'] . "', unit_id='" . $_GET['unit_id'] . "', description='" . $_GET['description'] . "';";
    echo $sql;
} else {
    $sql = "UPDATE xp_subunit SET rgt = rgt+2 WHERE rgt > " . $_GET['lft'] . "; ";
    $sql .="INSERT INTO xp_subunit SET level=" . $level . ", lft =" . $_GET['rgt'] . ", rgt =  " . $rgt . " , name = '" . $_GET['name'] . "', unit_id='" . $_GET['unit_id'] . "', description='" . $_GET['description'] . "';";
    echo $sql;
}
echo $query = $this->db->insert($this->tablename, $sql);
```

**Query for deleting record from database:**

```
$sql .= "SELECT @myLeft := " . $_GET['lft'] . ", @myRight :=  " . $_GET['rgt'] . ", @myWidth :=  " . $_GET['lft'] . " - lft + 1
    FROM xp_subunit WHERE id =" . $_GET['id'] . "; ";
$sql .= "DELETE FROM xp_subunit WHERE lft BETWEEN @myLeft AND @myRight; ";
$sql .= "UPDATE xp_subunit SET rgt = rgt - @myWidth WHERE rgt > @myRight; ";
$sql .= "UPDATE xp_subunit SET lft = lft - @myWidth WHERE lft > @myRight; ";
echo $query = $this->db->mysqli_multi_query($sql);
```

Whats wrong with above queries?

Comment: You haven't posted any code following your "Whats wrong with following code."...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used batch update and insert functions are available. The codeigniter's used guide will help you. Try the following link:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the potential sql injection ($_GET['...']), in the first query you use $this->db->insert().  This fails since insert() is part of the [ActiveRecord](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#insert) library, and used to construct queries, rather than execute them.

As for why mysqli_multi_query fails, I have no idea.  However, I would suggest not to use any driver-specific function since Code-Igniter allows you to abstract from the database.  So you should rather execute each query separately using [$this->db->query()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html).

That being said, I strongly suggest to use [ActiveRecord](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#insert).  It allows you to write queries without having to worry about the small syntax differences between databases.  Moreover, it escapes inputs automatically.

*edit*

The first update query would be:

```
$this->db->set('lft', 'lft+2', false);
$this->db->set('rgt', 'rgt+2', false);
$this->db->where('rgt >', $_GET['rgt']);
$this->db->update('xp_subunit');
```

The first insert:

```
$this->db->set('level', $level);
$this->db->set('lft', $_GET['rgt']);
...
$this->db->insert('xp_subunit');
```

and so on.. (have a look at the documentation)

Answer (score 0):

There are batch update and insert functions available - see below

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,'name' => 'My Name 2' , 'date' => 'My date 2'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,'name' => 'Another Name 2' , 'date' => 'Another date 2'
   )
);

$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'title');

// Produces:
// UPDATE `mytable` SET `name` = CASE
// WHEN `title` = 'My title' THEN 'My Name 2'
// WHEN `title` = 'Another title' THEN 'Another Name 2'
// ELSE `name` END,
// `date` = CASE
// WHEN `title` = 'My title' THEN 'My date 2'
// WHEN `title` = 'Another title' THEN 'Another date 2'
// ELSE `date` END
// WHERE `title` IN ('My title','Another title')
```

**For Insert**

```
$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
```

There is also $this->db->query() function available `$this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE');`

```
To Update and Insert - You'll need to execute them separately
```

//Update

```
$data = array(
               'title' => $title,'name' => $name,'date' => $date);

$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('mytable', $data);
```

//Insert

```
$data = array(
   'title' => 'My title' ,'name' => 'My Name' ,'date' => 'My date');
$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
```

//Delete

```
$this->db->delete('mytable', array('id' => $id));
```

**Note that**

Instead of using $_GET use

```
$this->input->get(NULL, TRUE); // returns all GET items with XSS filter
```

or

```
$this->input->get('some_data', TRUE);
```

Ref: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html